# I cannot install android sdk on AWS linux T.T

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-integration, amazon-ami

now i am trying to builing a CI environment for android with AWS EC2(aws linux ami) + Jenkins.

BTW, i am stuck in installing specific version of SDK, build-tools and  accepting the license agreement of the SDK on AWS EC2 linux.

at first when i ran the build on jenkins, jenkins gave me the ***ERROR*** like below.

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>   [Android SDK Build-Tools 24.0.2, Android SDK Platform 25].
>     Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>     Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

so i tried to run below few commands.

```
    -> cd /var/lib/jenkins/android/tools/
    -> sudo chmod 777 android
    -> android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-24.0.2,android-25,extra-android-m2repository
```

but... CLI complained to me like below at end of the installing sdk..

```
{....some installing step logs....}
November 20, 2015
Do you accept the license 'android-sdk-license-c81a61d9' [y/n]: y

Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24.0.2
  Failed to create directory /var/lib/jenkins/android/temp
  Downloading SDK Platform Android 7.1.1, API 25, revision 3
  Failed to create directory /var/lib/jenkins/android/temp
  Downloading Android Support Repository, revision 47
  Failed to create directory /var/lib/jenkins/android/temp
  Done. Nothing was installed.
```

It said `Failed to craete directory /var/lib/jenkins/android/temp` etcetra..

finally it said Done. ***Nothing was installed.***

i'd appreciate some help.

Comment: fyi, with many tries, i found the solution myself, `sudo ./android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-24.0.2,android-25,extra-android-m2repository` worked..